# angular2 : update very large rows base on timer interval

Tags: html, angular, timer, rxjs, observable

I am trying to update very large rows (approx 2000) on every 1 or 2
   seconds. I am using following solution but sometimes browser going to
   hang so looking for alternate solution. One issue with this solution
   is function "updatetime" in HTML template calling automatically.

```
<tr *ngFor="let item of list">
   <td>{{item.sessionid}} </td>
   <td>{{ updatetime(item.lastupdatedon) }} </td>
</tr>

ngOnInit() {
   let timer = Observable.timer(2000,3000);
   timer.subscribe(t=> this.ticks = t );
} 

public updatetime(lastupdated : Date) : any {
   update time
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about how your application behaves, but you should get the updates from server and when you receive the update packet, You need to simply fetch/filter the data stored in array (based on some id) and simply update only those values where ever Id's matches in the data you have vs received from server.